# How to make a application output for linux from nwjs?

Tags: linux, nwjs

Hi I am new to nwjs I made a small application using nwjs and used this following command to create a build for linux

```
nwbuild -v latest -p linux32 ./
```

Now this gave me this following files.
[image: files generated]

I want to make this open my application with a icon for this I wrote this following lines of code in a file named **.desktop** file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=sample
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose
Exec=/opt/sample/sample %F
Terminal=false
MimeType=text/plain;
Icon=sublime-text
Categories=TextEditor;Development;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=Window;Document;

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=New Window
Exec=/opt/sample/sample -n
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action Document]
Name=New File
Exec=/opt/sample/sample --command new_file
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

But my application is not opening. How to make this happen. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Where is your application installed?  What does the Exec command (`/opt/sample/sample --command new_file`)return in a terminal And why do you have the `OnlyShowIn=Unity;`?

Comment: I dont know to write a .desktop file this is a sample I got online @m.nachury

Answer (score 0):

Well this deskop file should be enougth:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=sample
Exec=Path to your exec file
Terminal=false
```

Juste change **Path to your exec file** by your exec file path (may need a chmod +x to be executable)

Comment: Did you see my image attached Which one is executable file Can you please tell me?

Comment: With njws the exec is actually nw, although you have to specify the path to your build. So something like that I guess. `nw ~/Destkop/build/nw-demo/linux64`. Btw this command should also work simply in terminal.

Comment: Also, you might want to move that out of your ~ if you want another user to use it.

Comment: I am getting this error while double clicking .desktop file. Untrusted application launcher

Comment: Oh, right, you have to run this `chmod +x ~/home/*.desktop ` to allow yourself launching the.desktop.

Comment: Or more direclty : `chmod +x pathToYourDeskopFile`.

Comment: I am getting this error. There was an error launching application

Comment: Try running `nw ~/Destkop/build/nw-demo/linux64` on a terminal. What is the ouput?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149802/discussion-between-m-nachury-and-anu).

Comment: This is what i found in nwjs official documentaion.On Linux, you need to create proper .desktop file.To create a self-extractable installer script, you can use scripts like shar or makeself.To distribute your app through the package management system, like apt, yum, pacman etc, please follow their official documents to create the packages. What should i do with this? any idea?